# why does simple update query in mysql keeps giving error code 1064?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is the query:

```
update table tblprobleem set omschrijving='bugfixes' where probleem_id=4;
```

I checked `omschrijving`, its datatype is `varchar`. `probleem_id` is integer. I tried to rewrite it a thousand times, I just don't get what is wrong with this.

error message:

> 12:03:05  update table tblprobleem set omschrijving='bugfixes' where
>   probleem_id=4
>
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'table tblprobleem set omschrijving='bugfixes'
>   where probleem_id=4' at line 1    0.000 sec

If anybody has the answer, you have my thanks forevere.

Greetz,
John

Comment: Its not `update table tblprobleem` its `update tblprobleem`

Comment: Thank you very much! Not sure why with all the rewriting why i never gave that a shot. I was convinced it had to be there i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the table in your query make it like this

```
update tblprobleem set omschrijving='bugfixes' where probleem_id=4
```